# Attempt to use a deleted function in std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, pointers

My code is as follows:

```
void internal_listener(TNReceiver *t){
    std::string oldVal = "";
    while (true) {
        void *holder = t+OFFSET;
        std::string val = *(std::string *)holder;
        if(val == oldVal){

        }else{
            time_t tine;
            std::cout << "[" << time(&tine) << "] : Logger msg recv: " << val;
        }
    }
}

TNReceiver::TNReceiver(int reg){
    this->REGISTER_ID = reg;
}

void TNReceiver::register_to_net(TNNet *net){
    net->add_transceiver(new TNData(this->REGISTER_ID, ""));
}

void TNReceiver::start_listen(){
    std::thread listen{this};
    listen.join();
}
```

How do I fix this? Error is at `std::thread listen{this}`. I do not want to pass a "copy" of `TNReceiver`. Any solutions would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to copy construct a thread, you'll get an error because the copy constructor is deleted.  You can however move construct a thread:

```
thread t1(f); 
thread t2 {std::move(t1)};   // move construct.  
t2.join();
```

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/4g7R8I)

But then the active thread is no longer attached to the initial object.   In your code, this could give some problems because apparently the object constructing the new thread is itself a thread and this might then break some of your assumptions.

*Note: your intent is not completely clear as you create a thread only to join it immediately afterwards.  If you add more information about your intent and the `TNReceiver` post a comment and I'll update*